# Linux + Active Directory + login format

Tags: linux

Can someone answer or point me in the right direction to allow users to login into linux boxes, via ssh, using only their username without specifying the domain?

Example:

joeshmoe@172.16.1.50(my linux box)  as oppose to  joeschome@mydomain.com@172.16.1.50(mylinuxbox)'

I would like to do without, specifying what domain the ID comes from, regardless if it interferes with local accounts. I'd like to set it it where no local accounts are created and only AD accounts are used.  Specifying the domain will get old.

ADDITIONAL INFO

id output:
[CORP\testuser@puppet ~]$ id
uid=16777216(CORP\testuser) gid=16777216(CORP\domain users) groups=16777216(CORP\domain users),16777217(CORP\chicago_unixadmins)

if i do "id test user"  , says no such user , i need to specify testuser@mydomain.com

I am authenticating against a windows 2008 server, with identity service for unix,

Im using winbind and kerberos for authentication , i followed the resource below, very simple and straight forward

http://funwithlinux.net/2013/10/join-centos-6-to-active-directory-domain/#more-784

Comment: I have never, ever seen this in all my years of unix administration, ever when authenticating to AD.  What is the output of `id` when a user is logged in?

Comment: You should put additional information about your server. How you integrated AD with Unix and what's you sAMAccountName and User Principal Name for example.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *.domain.com
User user@mydomain.com
```

Then all your users would have to do is:

```
$ ssh hostname.domain.com
```